# How can I make git list all changed files of a certain type in a specific path for a specific bug?

Tags: git, git-log, git-status

I would like to know how to make git list all changed files

- of a certain type (e.g. all php files)
- filed under a certain bug no. or which are still uncommitted
- and are in a specific path

I'll start with laying out an example situation for my question.

Say I have changed the following files:

**Uncommitted changes**

```
/site/main.php
/site/main.html
/site/includes/lib.php
```

**Commit 3**
Commit message: "Bug xyz: Made some changes"

```
/site/main.php
/site/main.html
/site/main.js
/test/test.php
/test/test.html
```

**Commit 2**
Commit message: "Bug xyz: Made some more changes"

```
/site/main.php
/site/main.html
/site/includes/include.php
```

**Commit 1**
Commit message: "Bug abc: Note that this is another bug"

```
/site/login.php
```

Say I'm still working on bug xyz. Now I need a list of all php files that have been changed so far in the site directory for this bug. So I would need the following list as output:

```
/site/main.php
/site/includes/lib.php
/site/includes/include.php
```

What command can do this?

Answer (score 9):

This is close:

```
git log --grep=xyz -- '*.php'
```

The `--grep` argument is applied to the commit messages.  The single quotes on the files argument ensures that `git` does the expansion.

A test:

```
ebg@ebg(328)$ git log --oneline
f687708 bar x, y, not a
dfb4b96 foo d, e, f
df18118 foo a, b, c
ebg@ebg(329)$ git log --oneline --grep=a
f687708 bar x, y, not a
df18118 foo a, b, c
ebg@ebg(330)$ git log --oneline --grep=a -- 'a.*'
df18118 foo a, b, c
```

The file expansion might need something to handle subdirectories.  Sort of:

```
git log --oneline --grep=a -- '*/a.*' 'a.*'
```